# Writing systems as $Ax = b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, boundary-value-problem

Let's say I have the following system:
$$-x_{i-1} + 2x_i - x_{i+1} = 1/(n+1)^2$$
for $i = 1, \ldots , n$ where $x_0 = 0$, $x_{n+1} = 0$, and $n = 20$

This systems happens to approximate a boundary value problem $-u'' = 1$ on $(0,1)$ with conditions $u(0) = u(1) = 0$

I want to write the system as $Ax = b$ but am slightly confused since:

- $i = 1$ only has $x_0$, $x_1$, and $x_2$ in the equation.
- $i = 2$ has  $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$
- etc...

Does this lead to a tri-diagonal matrix A with each row corresponding to a different value of $i$? I know the $\mathbf{x}$ vector needs to contain $x$ from $0 \to n+1$, which means the number of columns should match.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the matrix $A$ you get will be tri-diagonal. Each row will correspond to the first equation for one value of $i$. Also, $x$ doesn't need to contain an entry for $x_0$ or $x_{n+1}$ since those are both $0$.